# Executing Methods One After Another in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

In my application I have four methods like

```
- (void)Method1;  
- (void)Method2;  
- (void)Method3;  
- (void)Method4;
```

I want to execute these methods one after another. I search for this one in some sources they are using "dispatch_Time" in some sources they are using "NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:" But in my application I don't want to execute those methods using time. I want to execute them if the previous method execution is completed. How can I do this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you tell what are you doing in those methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040024/how-do-i-perform-several-methods-in-sequence

Comment: Why don't you use: `[self Method1]; [self Method2]; [self Method3]; [self Method4];` ? Do they perform some work in background?

Comment: As execution of normal code (i.e not written in particular thread) is done in main thread, it's all serial in that case. So calling methods just one after another should just work as Zapko said.

Comment: The Main Problem Here is i want to use variable values from the First Method in the second Method i call like this it show the value  to 0.

Answer (score 4):

## Solution Overview

The right way of doing this is to enqueue the methods onto a serial queue.

A serial queue executes one task at a time and thus ensures that a task is only executed once all it's predecessors were executed.

There are several ways of accomplishing what you wish. I will describe 2 of them, one using Grand Central Dispatch and one using `NSOperationQueue`.

### Grand Central Dispatch

1. Create a queue onto you will enqueue your task. A good practice would be to keep the queue as an instance variable so that you could access it from instance methods (unlike `NSOperationQueue`, by default custom dispatch queues are serial by default, i.e. they execute one task at a time):

   `dispatch_queue_t my_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.suresh.methodsqueue", NULL);
   self.methods_queue = my_queue;`
2. Enqueue your methods onto the designated queue one after the other:

   `dispatch_async(self.methods_queue, ^{ [someObject method1] });
   dispatch_async(self.methods_queue, ^{ [someObject method2] });
   dispatch_async(self.methods_queue, ^{ [someObject method3] });
   dispatch_async(self.methods_queue, ^{ [someObject method4] });`

[Further re GCD in Apple's developer guides.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1)

### Operation Queue

1. Initialize a queue:

   `NSOperationQueue* aQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
   self.methods_queue = aQueue;`
2. Make sure the queue is serial:

   `[self.methods_queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1]`
3. Enqueue the methods onto the queue, there's several ways of doing so, the following requires the least amount of code:

   `[self.methods_queue addOperationWithBlock:^{ [someObject method1] }];
   [self.methods_queue addOperationWithBlock:^{ [someObject method2] }];
   [self.methods_queue addOperationWithBlock:^{ [someObject method3] }];
   [self.methods_queue addOperationWithBlock:^{ [someObject method4] }];`

[Further re Operation Queues in Apple's developer guides.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1)

Comment: Sorry but I have a few questions. The Serial queue didn't solve my problem if I want to achieve something like this: async method2 will execute after the completion of async method1. It cannot achieve what 'promisekit' did.

Answer (score 2):

If the methods don't return until they've finished their work, just call them in order:

```
[self Method1];
[self Method2];
[self Method3];
[self Method4];
```

Otherwise, you need to use something like dispatch groups.

Answer (score -2):

call first method somewhere like

```
[self (void)Method1];
```

and implement like

```
(void)Method1{

   // logic here 
  [self (void)Method2];
}

(void)Method2{

   // logic here 
  [self (void)Method3];
}
```

and so on ...............